# Categoricity of integers under "less-than"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across the following remark in Stewart Shapiro's [*The Governance of Identity*](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=94YUnW5iiVEC&oi=fnd&pg=PA164&ots=Mlvh9Klz5D&sig=lztdOYXOwmpAu8zhmBSDu-b6orI#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Consider, for example, a structure S with a single relation, <. The
>   axioms of S are that < is a linear order, there is no first or last
>   element, and for any two elements x, y, there are only finitely-many
>   z, such that x < z < y. Every model of this theory is isomorphic to
>   the integers, under ‘less-than’. So it is categorical.

Now I didn't know that the (second-order) theory of the integers (under "less-than") was categorical. Is that what is being asserted here? Does anyone have a reference to a proof of the categoricity in question (or could provide one themselves)?

Comment: This is not a first-order theory, because of the "finitely many condition. No first-order theory with an infinite model is categorical.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I figured as much (that it couldn't be first-order for precisely the reason you state). Are you just noting that to add another piece to the puzzle, are you noting that because something in my question suggests it should be first-order, or for some other reason entirely?

Comment: I was just concerned that an inexperienced person might think it was first-order, since for a long time it has been the default assumption.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Fair enough. I'll add that to the question to aid comprehension for the less experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given axioms we can prove that every elements has an immediate successor and an immediate predecessor: Since there's no largest element, an arbitrary element $x$ has *some* successor $y>x$. If there are any elements between $x$ and $y$, there must be finitely many of them $x$ and $y$, and one of those must be first.

Now we can construct an order-preserving map $f:\mathbb Z\to S$, by choosing $f(0)$ arbitrarily, and then recursively setting $f(n+1)$ to the immediate successor of $f(n)$ and $f(-n-1)$ to the immediate predecessor of $f(-n)$.

It should be easy to see that $f$ preserves order, and therefore $f$ is injective. If we can also show $f$ is surjective, it must be an isomorphism.

Assume to the contrary that there is some $a\in S$ that is not hit by $f$. Let's say that $a>f(0)$; the other case is similar. But then, by induction on $n$ we must have $a>f(n)$ too for $n\in\mathbb N_+$, because each $f(n)$ is by construction the *immediate* successor of the previous one. But then all of these $f(n)$ are between $f(0)$ and $a$, contradicting the last axiom.